# Delinquent 10 days after due date?

Tags: phrases

If a bill is due on 6th and becomes delinquent on the next day, and penalty charge will start if payment is not made within 10 days after the due date (that is, 6th), then does the penalty start to incur on 16th or 17th?

Comment: This strike me as more of a [law.se] question than a Language one, is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

"Within ten days after the due date" is not a very common expression, but it seems to refer to the ten days numbered from 7th to 16th (inclusive). Making the payment on 16th would be within the ten days after the due date. The 17th is not within those ten days.

A more usual expression might be "within ten days of the due date", but that **could** be ambiguous as to how the due date itself is counted, and that could make 16th the first penalty day. Using *after* makes it clear that the due date itself is not counted, and the grace period starts with the day following the due date. As our [prepositions](/questions/tagged/prepositions) tag help itself says, "The meaning of a sentence can be dramatically altered by choosing the wrong preposition."

Whether a judge in a particular jurisdiction would agree with this assessment of *after* is outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

> If a bill is due on 6th and becomes delinquent on the next day, and **the/a** penalty charge will start if payment is not made within 10 days after the due date (that is, 6th), then does the penalty start to incur on 16th or 17th?

First some definitions:

**Within** = **inside** a given length, area, volume, or duration

**Day** = a period of 24hrs starting at one second past midnight on one day and lasting until one second before midnight on the same day.

**After** = that follow(s)

**a bill is due on 6th** = a bill must be paid before 11:59:59 p.m. on the 6th

**Midnight** = a single, infinitesimal point in time that does not belong to any one day and that occurs one second after 11:59:59 pm.

**NB:** To all intents and purposes, the time between 11:59:59 p.m. on, for example, Monday and 00:00:01 a.m. on Tuesday does not exist.

Thus note the differences between

1 The penalty begins **immediately**, i.e. at 00:00:01 a.m. on the 7th, i.e. the start of the day that immediately follow(s) the due date.

2 The penalty begins **within one day** of delinquency, i.e. 11:59:59 p.m. on the 7th

3 The penalty begins **after one day** of delinquency, i.e. 00:00:01 a.m. on the 8th

Thus, in answer to your question, **the penalty starts to incur on 16th at 11:59:59 p.m.**

*Your next question is probably “When is payment said to be “made”? At the time that the person makes the payment, or at the time that the time that the other person receives it?” That should be asked in the Law Forum.*

Comment: Your "to all intents and purposes" sentence is not correct; the duration of the period between 23:59:59 and 00:00:01 is two seconds. What you actually appear to be saying is that the penalty becomes payable at 00:00:00 on 17th, which is what I wrote.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Your answer did not refer to a particular time. OED "*P2. to (for) all intents and purposes (less usually to all intents): in regard to any end or object, **for all practical purposes**, ‘practically’.*" The practicality lies in my not having to discuss the unnecessary arguments and explanations around 00:00:00 and 24:00:00.